# Kotlin secondary constructor of extended class conditional branch super value

Tags: constructor, kotlin

How do you have conditional super calls based on the value in the fourth secondary constructor?
Why doesn't this work?

```
open class SecondaryConstructors{
    constructor(i:Int)
    constructor(s:String)
}
class SecondaryExtended:SecondaryConstructors {
    constructor(i:Int):super(i)
    constructor(s:String):super(s)
    constructor():super(if(true)1 else 0)
    constructor(intOrString:Boolean):super( if(intOrString) 3 else "hey")
    // conditional branch result of int/string is implicitly cast to Any
    // error - none of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied
}
```

Comment: Why would you need this? In practice I'd use a companion object with a factory function.

Comment: @9000 No need just exploring, going through the Kotlin In Action book, yet to learn about companion objects.

Comment: This isn't expressible in Java either.

Comment: Question is not limited to secondary constructors, the error persists with `SecondaryExtended(if(true)3 else "hey")`
Should I change the title to "Passing in branch conditional typed values to a constructor" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This won't work as your `if` expression passed as the constructor's argument has no unique type, except `Any`, which is the most common type. You're getting an error since there isn't a matching constructor expecting `Any` as an argument.

```
constructor(intOrString:Boolean):
super( if(intOrString) 3 else "hey")
```

It's not possible, same as in Java, to make a conditional super call. The super type has to be initialized directly, as the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#inheritance) tells:

> If the class has no primary constructor, then each secondary constructor 
>   has to initialize the base type using the super keyword, or to delegate to > another constructor which does that. Note that in this case different 
>   secondary constructors can call different constructors of the base type

Comment: Ok, could you please show an example, I've tried a few ways but couldn't get the syntax right.

Comment: I can do later, for know I edited my answer because I'm not 100% sure if it's possible at all. Let me have a look at it

Comment: Sorry @ersin-ertan I cannot see a way to this